# Error in tabular: missing item. Suppress or fix?

Tags: tables

I am getting error's on line 8 "perhaps a missing item" for this code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{table:proberesults}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccccccc@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{False positives} \\ \cmidrule(l){4-8} 
    \textbf{Participant} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Hours of use}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Positives}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Physical\\ movement\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Concentrated \\ work\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Unknown\\ cause\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Social \\ interaction\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Incorrect\\ use\end{tabular}} \\ \midrule
    \#1 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 1 &  &  \\
    \#2 & 8 & 6 & 8 & 1 & 1 & 3 &  \\
    \#3 & 12 & 6 & 1 &  & 1 &  & 5 \\
    \#4 & 12 & 0* &  &  & 2 & 1 &  \\
    \#5 & 5 & 2 &  &  & 2 &  &  \\
    \#6 & 2 & 0 & 2 &  & 2 & 2 &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I do not really care that there is an error in there, the table looks fine on print.

Is there a way I can suppress all warnings/error reporting for this one file "table.tex"? Also if anyone have a suggestion on how to fix the error that would also be great.

Edit: this my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{apalike}
\usepackage[autostyle, threshold=40, thresholdtype=words]{csquotes}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[textlf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{6pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{0pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}{1\baselineskip}
\setlist{noitemsep}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\begin{center}\small}
    \AfterEndEnvironment{tabular}{\end{center}}
```

Comment: Well there is no error in this code. Please post a MWE to show us what "error" you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

I am also unable to replicate the issue you say you're getting, using just the information you've provided.

At any rate, I'd like to question your claim that "the table looks fine on print". For instance, unless the text block of your document is usually wide, the table will protrude into the right-hand margin. I suggest you use a `tabularx` environment to ensure that the tabular material fits within the text block. Another suggestion: Don't use **boldface** for the material in the header cells: It's not needed. Really.

The following screenshot shows both the suggested layout and the layout produced by your code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=1in]{geometry} % set text block parameters
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e,mathtools,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{@{}C@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{My caption}
\label{table:proberesults}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}
      c S[table-format=2.0] *6{c} @{}}
\toprule
&&& \multicolumn{5}{c}{False positives} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){4-8} 
Participant & {Hours of use} & Positives & 
\mC{Physical movement} & \mC{Concentrated work} & 
\mC{Unknown cause} & \mC{Social interaction} & 
\mC{Incorrect use} \\ 
\midrule
    \#1 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 1 &  &  \\
    \#2 & 8 & 6 & 8 & 1 & 1 & 3 &  \\
    \#3 & 12 & 6 & 1 &  & 1 &  & 5 \\
    \#4 & 12 & 0$\mathrlap{^*}$ &  &  & 2 & 1 &  \\
    \#5 & 5 & 2 &  &  & 2 &  &  \\
    \#6 & 2 & 0 & 2 &  & 2 & 2 &  \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{For comparison: Original form of table}
\label{table:proberesults}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cccccccc@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{False positives} \\ \cmidrule(l){4-8} 
    \textbf{Participant} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Hours of use}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Positives}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Physical\\ movement\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Concentrated \\ work\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Unknown\\ cause\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Social \\ interaction\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Incorrect\\ use\end{tabular}} \\ \midrule
    \#1 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 1 &  &  \\
    \#2 & 8 & 6 & 8 & 1 & 1 & 3 &  \\
    \#3 & 12 & 6 & 1 &  & 1 &  & 5 \\
    \#4 & 12 & 0* &  &  & 2 & 1 &  \\
    \#5 & 5 & 2 &  &  & 2 &  &  \\
    \#6 & 2 & 0 & 2 &  & 2 & 2 &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. You are right about the bold typeface! Also, you are right about the table exceeding the \linewidth. I will try your example and see how it goes. Thank you!

Comment: Updated question with my preamble. I am getting undefined control sequence \end{tabularx} with your solution.

Comment: I was missing ragged2e! Thank you a lot for your help, I will accept your answer.

Comment: You'll get your upvote when I reach 15 reputation points ;) Really, thank you, I would have never figured that out.